# Update Query Access 2007 Group into one row

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I'm playing around with access and vba. I'm struggleing to update and to group rows from tblLoadingListItems into tblLoadSummary using the query below

```
 UPDATE tblLoadSummary INNER JOIN tblLoadingListItems ON (tblLoadSummary.salesno = tblLoadingListItems.salesno) AND (tblLoadSummary.loadnolink = tblLoadingListItems.loadnolink) SET tblLoadSummary.[Cust O/N] = [tblLoadingListItems].[Cust O/N], tblLoadSummary.traderid = [tblLoadingListItems].[traderid], tblLoadSummary.street = [tblLoadingListItems].[street], tblLoadSummary.[zone] = [tblLoadingListItems].[zone], tblLoadSummary.salesno = [tblLoadingListItems].[salesno], tblLoadSummary.[Customer Ref] = [tblLoadingListItems].[Customer Ref], tblLoadSummary.DeliveryAddress = [tblLoadingListItems].[DeliveryAddress], tblLoadSummary.Postcode = [tblLoadingListItems].[Postcode], tblLoadSummary.SumOfnoofpacks = Sum([tblLoadingListItems].[packs1]), tblLoadSummary.SumOfnoofboxes = Sum([tblLoadingListItems].[noofboxes]), tblLoadSummary.contact = [tblLoadingListItems].[contact], tblLoadSummary.telephone = [tblLoadingListItems].[telephone], tblLoadSummary.fax = [tblLoadingListItems].[fax], tblLoadSummary.email = 
[tblLoadingListItems].[email], tblLoadSummary.deliverycontact = [tblLoadingListItems].[deliverycontact], tblLoadSummary.deliverytelephone = [tblLoadingListItems].[deliverytelephone], tblLoadSummary.deliveryfax = [tblLoadingListItems].[deliveryfax], tblLoadSummary.deliveryemail = [tblLoadingListItems].[deliveryemail], tblLoadSummary.acknowaddress = [tblLoadingListItems].[acknowaddress]

 WHERE (((tblLoadSummary.salesno)="SM-100118") AND ((tblLoadSummary.loadnolink)=32232))
```

If i show datasheet view i get two rows returned, Im trying to group these rows into one.
When i try to add a GROUP BY after the WHERE i get syntax errors missing operators for all my fields.

Can you someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what is the error ? I am not familiar with access but i dont think you cannot update table join set ... its update table set ... join ...

Comment: There is no way to add Group By to an update query. Aggregating queries are always read-only.

Comment: So, if table a has 2 duplicates lines ( bar one qty field) i cant update one line in table b with the existing information + the sum qty?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure with access but starting update like this and maybe its wrong :

```
Update tblLoadSummary inner join...
```

try it like this

```
 update t set .... from tblLoadSummary t inner join tblLoadSummary s on ...
```

this is the full query

```
UPDATE t-- tblLoadSummary 
   SET t.CustO/N = s.CustO/N,
       t.traderid          = s.traderid,
       t.street            = s.street,
       t.zone = s.zone,
       t.salesno           = s.salesno,
       t.CustomerRef = s.Customer Ref,
       t.DeliveryAddress   = s.DeliveryAddress,
       t.Postcode          = s.Postcode,
       t.SumOfnoofpacks    = Sum(s.packs1),
       t.SumOfnoofboxes    = Sum(s.noofboxes),
       t.contact           = s.contact,
       t.telephone         = s.telephone,
       t.fax               = s.fax,
       t.email             = s.email,
       t.deliverycontact   = s.deliverycontact,
       t.deliverytelephone = s.deliverytelephone,
       t.deliveryfax       = s.deliveryfax,
       t.deliveryemail     = s.deliveryemail,
       t.acknowaddress     = s.acknowaddress
from tblLoadSummary as t
 INNER JOIN tblLoadingListItems as s ON 
 (t.salesno = s.salesno) AND (t.loadnolink = s.loadnolink)
 WHERE (((t.salesno) = "SM-100118") AND
       ((t.loadnolink) = 32232))
```